# Tokens from text

Tags: r

I try to run this command:

```
text_cleaning_tokens <- data %>%      tidytext::unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

And I receive this error:

```
Error: object ‘vec_rep_each’ is not exported by 'namespace:vctrs'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to vctrs not being updated. See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/issues/191

In brief, try: `update.packages()` and then forcing with `install.packages("vctrs")`